# Sun Script RenderProbe on time of day

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm tring to make a unity sun script that renders the light probe at certain time of the day taken from an array.
The day is from 0-1 interval ( 0 night, 0.25 sunrise, 0.5 midday, 0.75 sunset, 1 night)

To be honest even if I check the statement currentTimeOfDay == 0.75  when the value is reached the print does not occur

And how do I check the statement for multiple array?

```
   public float secondsInFullDay = 120f;
   [Range(0,1)]
   public float currentTimeOfDay = 0f;
   private float[] floatDay = new float[4] {0f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 0.75f};
   public float timeMultiplier = 1f;



  void Update() {

        currentTimeOfDay += (Time.deltaTime / secondsInFullDay) * timeMultiplier;

        if (currentTimeOfDay >= 1) {
            currentTimeOfDay = 0;
        }


    if(currentTimeOfDay == floatDay[0]){
        reflectionProbe.RenderProbe();
        print ("refresh probe");
        }


}
```

This only prints at 0 value

```
foreach (float x in floatDay){

    if (x.Equals (currentTimeOfDay)){
        print ("refresh probe");
    }

}
```

L.E

I managed to check the statement against array but it prints multiple times that means that will cause unnecessary load
If the time timeMultiplier is set to 10 instead of 1 then the print is one time when reached the value.

Is there a way to multiply the array with a float and get new array?

```
private float[] floatDay = new float[4] {0, 250, 500, 750};

    TimeOfDay = currentTimeOfDay * 1000 * timeMultiplier;
    TimeOfDay = Mathf.Round(TimeOfDay);


    foreach (float x in floatDay){
        if (TimeOfDay == x){
            reflectionProbe.RenderProbe();
            print ("refresh probe");
        }       
    }
```

L.E 2

fixed it , but doesn't seem that compact but it works

```
private float[] floatDay = new float[4] {0, 2500, 5000, 7500};  

    TimeOfDay = currentTimeOfDay * 10000 / timeMultiplier;
    TimeOfDay = Mathf.Round(TimeOfDay);


    foreach (float x in floatDay){
      float y = x / timeMultiplier;
        if (TimeOfDay == y){
            reflectionProbe.RenderProbe();
            print ("refresh probe");
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This only prints at 0 value

```
foreach (float x in floatDay){
    if (x.Equals (currentTimeOfDay)){
        print ("refresh probe");
    }
}
```

because floating points are never accurate. Your value in never exactly equal to the value you compare it to.

Use this instead:

```
foreach (float x in floatDay){
    if (x > currentTimeOfDay - 1e-7f && x < currentTimeOfDay + 1e-7f){
        print ("refresh probe");
    }
}
```

if it still doesn't work, change 1e-7f to 1e-6f, 1e-5f, etc...